# Is it possible to use haxe to build mac native application?

Tags: macos, haxe

I see Haxe can compile to many languages, but not sure is it possible to use it build a native mac(OSX) application? Like a small TODO list application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) or other framework ([Luxe](http://luxeengine.com/), [Kha](http://tech.ktxsoftware.com/kha/), [NME](http://github.com/haxenme/nme)) you could target Mac and get project that compiles via XCode into native application.

Comment: Thanks, seems they are all game or media engines, can I use them to build normal application? Like a todo list, notepad

Comment: I think yes, they has few UI frameworks (mostly on top of OpenFL) that you can use for making GUI:
http://www.haxeui.org/ 
https://github.com/RealyUniqueName/StablexUI
HaxeUI has few demos of apps, such as IRC client, Notepad etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want native OSX UI then there are libraries for that, such as Basis: https://github.com/Randonee/Basis. When using that you use the C++ target, and the library communicates with Objective C UI stuff via the C Foreign Function Interface. This comes with some limitations and depending on the status of the library, it could be hard to get started.

If you don't care about native UI then there are libraries that have what you need for simple notepad-type apps. In most cases you would still be able to use the C++ target. For example see Ian Harrigan's Haxe UI project: https://github.com/ianharrigan/haxeui